# Beginner C++, "no matching function call to" in constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, arduino

I'm trying to start my first Arduino project, a tiny 8-bit handheld game console.

So, i'm trying to do my first class. I'm extremely new to CPP, i've done tons of C# and java in the past.

Here's my code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <TFT.h>

class Menu {
  String menuTitle = "Menu";
  TFT TFTscreen;
  public:
    Menu(String title, TFT screen)
    {
      menuTitle = title;
      TFTscreen = screen;
    }

    void Update() {
      TFTscreen.setTextSize(2);
      TFTscreen.text(menuTitle, 0, 0);
    }
};
```

I get an error on the Menu constructor, it says "no matching function for call to 'TFT::TFT()' ". Why does this happen? Why can't I just run the constructor like

```
Menu menu = new Menu("Test Menu", scrn);
```

What am I missing and/or what do I have to do?

A few more questions:
Where's a good place to get into CPP? It's a little "different" coming from C#. I do not understand the entire point of "pointers" and a few other things.

One more:
If you happen to know anything about Arduino, is there ANY way I could run C# code on an arduino, by itself? Without having to be plugged into a computer?

Thank you guys!

Comment: How is `scrn` defined? And write seperate questions for seperate questions, please.

Comment: The issue of `TFT::TFT()` not defined doesn't come from the line you pasted (but rather from scrn definition like cad suggested). But the line you *think* is giving you an issue, still has an issue of trying to assign object of type `Menu*` to `Menu`. So either do `Menu menu ("Test Menu", scrn);`, or `Menu* menu = new Menu("Test Menu", scrn);` (if you need 2nd way of creating it - don't forget to delete it, there's no GC in C++, like there is in C#/Java.

Comment: My apologies, cad. scrn is a made up variable. scrn would be a working instance of TFT. I want to have ONE TFT variable in the main class and pass it to other classes that need it instead of having to make a new one. TFT is also a library that is built-in to the arduino IDE. I'd rather not mess with it. I just want to be able to pass my one TFT object to other classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it follows from the error message class `TFT` does not have the default constructor (a constructor that can be called without arguments).

Check the class definition.

The error occurs because there is called the default constructor of class `TFT`

```
class Menu {
  String menuTitle = "Menu";
  TFT TFTscreen;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  public:
    Menu(String title, TFT screen)
    {
      menuTitle = title;
      TFTscreen = screen;
    }
    //...
```

You could write the Menu constructor the following way

```
Menu( const String &title, const TFT &screen ) : menuTitle( title ), TFTscreen( screen )
{
}
```

(I am not sure whether String is a valid class name)

And because C++ is not C# you may not write

```
Menu menu = new Menu("Test Menu", scrn);
```

You have to write

```
Menu *menu = new Menu("Test Menu", scrn);
```

Or it seems you could write simply

```
Menu menu("Test Menu", scrn);
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it :)
I do not understand though, what is the & sign for? And why do you need const?

Comment: Why is the constructor being called and why do we need const? Please elaborate. Thank you

Comment: @Borna In this statement TFTscreen = screen; there is used the copy assignment operator. Itr is supposed that the object TFTscreen is already created using the default constructor. The qualifier const is needed because   a temporary object may be referred by a const lvalue reference.